# C++, libsodium, strange key

Tags: c++, encryption

in my project i use libsodium,
I have the simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "include/sodium.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    unsigned char key[crypto_secretbox_KEYBYTES];
    crypto_secretbox_keygen(key);

    cout << key << endl;
}
```

Here are a few example of key that the program generates:

```
key 0 : Æ$¢─‗↓Ïô*!■Î☼¼ðæ÷╗1rks×êÖ_è☼»¯┌bòÖ.¯×─

key 1 : wØ╚¿¾T▓­¯ª,Àó│Á½ía♣▀Ö°x!N8‼¥~å:ÂòÖ.¯×─

key 2 : ┼w↑¿*ÿî/¼ëp­}NjÔ╬YÉ¯cÀù{8óÕòÄ'òÖ.¯×─

key 3 : ┤ÃE╣¾
ó¶Î↕↨ê┤▀╦à☼.a¸À,Õ¨e└õ▓↑QzòÖ.¯×─

key 4 : ¦ã=¢ôJ╦ê├▀¶gödñ├←▓·foü@¶Ì╩¶%└±iòÖ.¯×─
```

The questions are:

1. why some key have sent to head ('\n'), example key number 3.
2. Is it normal that the key have strange characters.
3. Is there a way to get a key like this: kd943jssad3d920832usi28sa? (so not strange characters, for example, ▀±▓☼¼)

Comment: You're printing the raw binary key data. It sounds like you want to see a  hex or base64 *encoded* representation of the data.

Comment: key is set `unsigned char` that is normal.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, ok, so how can i view the key?

Comment: How do you want to represent the binary data? Hex? Octal? Base64? Uuencoded? There's no universal answer.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, i want to represent it in Unicode

Answer (score 1):

1. because \n was generated.
2. yes, these are extended ASCII codes.
3. depending on exactly why you need those key, a simple workaround is to clamp the character codes to the range of ASCII values that suits you (`isprint` range ?), after key generation.